# Custom Directive in Angular 2 App Not Working as Expected With Hover Event

Tags: angular, typescript, mouseover

In my Angular 2 app I have set up a custom directive to show and hide a delete icon based on when a user hovers over the relevant element. I'm pretty sure I've set up everything as recommended, however nothing happens when I hover over the element. This makes me wonder if the issue is that the directive is set up incorrectly, or if perhaps the component just isn't aware of it (i.e. -- I'm not importing it correctly for use in the component). By the way, I'm targeting the `.field-delete-btn` css class, which is applied to the delete icon I am trying to hide prior to a user hovering over it.

This is the directive itself:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: "[cloakIt]"
})
export class ElementDisplayDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef,
              private renderer: Renderer) {

  }

  @HostListener ('mouseover') onMouseOver() {
    let deleteIcon = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.field-delete-btn');
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(deleteIcon, 'display', 'inline');
    console.log('User moused over...');
  }

  @HostListener('mouseout') onMouseOut() {
    let deleteIcon = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.field-delete-btn');
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(deleteIcon, 'display', 'none');
    console.log('User moused out...');
  }
}
```

And, from my understanding, I just list the selector on the wrapping element I want to target, so since my directive selector is "cloakIt", I'm using it like this in the component view (since I wasn't sure whether to place "cloakIt" on the div or the span, I placed it on both for testing purposes):

```
<div *ngFor="let permission of client?.permissions; let i = index;" class="permission" cloakIt>
    <span class="capitalize" cloakIt>{{permission.department}}
          <i [style.display]="'none'" (click)="removePermission(i)" class="material-icons md-18 field-delete-btn" title="Delete a role">delete</i>
    </span>
</div>
```

At the minimum my console.log should be triggered upon hovering over the element, but nothing happens. I don't get any errors, just so recognition that a hover event has occurred. By the way, I have listed this directive in my root app.module -- and, as far as I know, that means it should now be available anywhere for use. However, for extra measure, though I don't think it should be necessary, I've also imported the directive in the component in which I'm using it.

So what's the issue here? Is there something wrong with the syntax or the way I've set up the custom directive, or is something else at issue?

**EDIT**

Here is a link to a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EgsmbXMN7s7YYDYIu9N8?p=preview) of which I followed the basic structure of in my custom directive.

Comment: Can you give a plnkr with that code?

Comment: I haven't set up a plunkr before, but here's an example of one that I followed the structure of: http://plnkr.co/edit/EgsmbXMN7s7YYDYIu9N8?p=preview

Comment: I haven't found any mistakes here, have you made sure your HTML element is "hoverable" in meaning not behind any other element or with no height or width etc?

Comment: If I can click to delete the icon (which I can if I change the [style.display] to 'inline;), would that mean that the element should also be hoverable? Or not necessarily? How can I check that?

Comment: Hmm yeah, it should... I'd check the element in Chrome DevTools. I added your directive to the plunker you provided and it works, take a [look](http://plnkr.co/edit/JA4u8KvZl69JNJ1vsTbS?p=preview).

Comment: `User moused over...` in console.

Comment: Right. I see that too.

Comment: I see you have your directive applied to the div container and span, try it without duplication, one directive probably overrides another.

Comment: Yeah, already tried that - tried applying it just to the div, and then just to the span. Unfortunately, it didn't make a difference. Which makes me wonder if the component is recognizing the directive at all.

Comment: Did you add `ElementDisplayDirective` in `@Declarations` in the module? a plunker for the code you provided works fine   http://embed.plnkr.co/f3W8kzhRdl2aQs3F2FxD/

Comment: @FetraR. That was it! I had it listed as a declaration in my root module, but not in the local module to this component. Once I moved it to that module instead the directive works as expected!

Comment: @Muirik I would suggest to delete the question, or provide an answer.

Comment: @FetraR. could you provide the answer so, can vote for you answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to add `ElementDisplayDirective` in `@Declarations` in the local module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...,
    ElementDisplayDirective
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

a plunker for the code you provided works fine https://embed.plnkr.co/f3W8kzhRdl2aQs3F2FxD